# Prove that $f(x) \to L$ and $g(x) \to M$ as $x \to x_0$ and $f(x) \leq g(x)$ implies that $L \leq M$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification

Here's what I'm trying to prove:

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions. Suppose that the following hold:

1. $f(x) \leq g(x)$
2. $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x) = M$

Then, $L \leq M$

---

Proof Attempt:

By hypothesis, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $\delta_1,\delta_2 > 0$ such that:

$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

$0 < |x-x_0| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x) - M| < \epsilon$

Let $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Then, if we have $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$, we get:

$L-\epsilon < f(x) \leq g(x) < M + \epsilon$

$\implies 0 < (M-L) + 2\epsilon$

Suppose that $M-L < 0$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{L-M}{2}$. Then, this gives us:

$0 < (M-L) + (L-M) = 0$

That is an absurdity. Hence, $M-L \geq 0$ so $M \geq L$. That proves the desired result.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, it's perfect.

Comment: Thank you so much!